# app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses FAILED in android studio

Tags: android-studio, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-vision

This are dependencies I added:
dependencies {

```
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:22.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    implementation 'com.github.VishnuSivadasVS:Advanced-HttpURLConnection:1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'



    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-vision:v1-rev357-1.22.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'

    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0'
    implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.20.0'



}
```

and I got this error but it works good in another project may be it due to dependency please help

Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> Duplicate class com.google.common.annotations.Beta found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.annotations.GwtCompatible found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.annotations.GwtIncompatible found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.annotations.VisibleForTesting found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.Absent found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.AbstractIterator found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.AbstractIterator$1 found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.AbstractIterator$State found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.Ascii found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.CaseFormat found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.CaseFormat$1 found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.CaseFormat$2 found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.CaseFormat$3 found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.CaseFormat$4 found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.CaseFormat$5 found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.CaseFormat$StringConverter found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.CharMatcher found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$1 found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$And found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$BitSetMatcher found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$FastMatcher found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$NegatedFastMatcher found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$Or found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.CharMatcher$RangesMatcher found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.Charsets found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.Converter found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.Converter$1 found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.Converter$1$1 found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.Converter$ConverterComposition found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.Converter$FunctionBasedConverter found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.Converter$IdentityConverter found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.Converter$ReverseConverter found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.Defaults found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.Enums found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.Enums$StringConverter found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.Equivalence found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.Equivalence$1 found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.Equivalence$Equals found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.Equivalence$EquivalentToPredicate found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.Equivalence$Identity found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.Equivalence$Wrapper found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.FinalizablePhantomReference found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.FinalizableReference found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.FinalizableReferenceQueue found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.FinalizableReferenceQueue$DecoupledLoader found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.FinalizableReferenceQueue$DirectLoader found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.common.base.FinalizableReferenceQueue$FinalizerLoader found in modules jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
> .............................